# Pandas DataFrame, calculate max column value relative to current row column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
    'epoch' : [1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17], 
    'price' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4]
} )

   epoch  price
0      1      1
1      4      2
2      7      3
3      8      3
4      9      1
5     11      4
6     12      2
7     15      3
8     16      4
9     17      4
```

I have to create a new column that should be calculated in the following way:

For each row

Find current row's epoch (let's say e_cur)

Calculate e_cur-3 = e_cur – 3 (three is a constant here but it will be variable)

Calculate price max value where epoch >= e-3_cur and epoch <= e_cur

In other words, find maximum price in rows that are three epoch away from current row's epoch.

For example:

Index=0, e_cur = epoch = 1, e_cur-3 = 1 -3 = -2, there is only one (first) row whose epoch is between -2 and 1 so the price from the first row is maximum price

Index =6, e_cur = epoch = 12, e_cur-3 = 12 – 3 = 9, there are three rows whose epoch is between 9 and 12, but row with index=5 has the maximum price = 4.

Here are the results for every row that I calculated manually:

```
   epoch  price  max_price_where_epoch_is_between_e_cur-3_and_e_cur
0      1      1                                                  1 
1      4      2                                                  2 
2      7      3                                                  3 
3      8      3                                                  3 
4      9      1                                                  3 
5     11      4                                                  4 
6     12      2                                                  4 
7     15      3                                                  3 
8     16      4                                                  4 
9     17      4                                                  4
```

As you can see, epoch something goes one by one, but sometimes there are "holes".

How to calculate that with pandas?

Comment: try `apply` should give back your right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using rolling window:

```
In [161]: df['between'] = df.epoch.map(df.set_index('epoch')
     ...:                                .reindex(np.arange(df.epoch.min(), df.epoch.max()+1))
     ...:                                .rolling(3, min_periods=1)
     ...:                                .max()['price'])
     ...:

In [162]: df
Out[162]:
   epoch  price  between
0      1      1      1.0
1      4      2      2.0
2      7      3      3.0
3      8      3      3.0
4      9      1      3.0
5     11      4      4.0
6     12      2      4.0
7     15      3      3.0
8     16      4      4.0
9     17      4      4.0
```

Explanation:

Helper DF:

```
In [165]: df.set_index('epoch').reindex(np.arange(df.epoch.min(), df.epoch.max()+1))
Out[165]:
       price
epoch
1        1.0
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        2.0
5        NaN
6        NaN
7        3.0
8        3.0
9        1.0
10       NaN
11       4.0
12       2.0
13       NaN
14       NaN
15       3.0
16       4.0
17       4.0

In [166]: df.set_index('epoch').reindex(np.arange(df.epoch.min(), df.epoch.max()+1)).rolling(3, min_periods=1).max()
Out[166]:
       price
epoch
1        1.0
2        1.0
3        1.0
4        2.0
5        2.0
6        2.0
7        3.0
8        3.0
9        3.0
10       3.0
11       4.0
12       4.0
13       4.0
14       2.0
15       3.0
16       4.0
17       4.0
```

Comment: Nice, it could be more efficient.

Comment: @tarashypka, thank you! Yes, it can always be more efficient... ;-)

Comment: Nice Idea, `reindex` always make life easier when missing value.

Answer (score 2):

Consider applying function on `epoch` column where you can locate the required rows and calculate their `price` max value

```
>> df['between'] = df['epoch'].apply(lambda e: df.loc[
>>                (df['epoch'] >= e - 3) & (df['epoch'] <= e), 'price'].max())
>> df
    epoch  price  between
 0      1      1        1
 1      4      2        2
 2      7      3        3
 3      8      3        3
 4      9      1        3
 5     11      4        4
 6     12      2        4
 7     15      3        3
 8     16      4        4
 9     17      4        4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both solutions, from tarashypka and MaxU.
The first solution I have tried was Tarashypka's. I tested it on 100k rows. It took about one minute.

Than I tried MaxU's solution, that has finished in about 4 seconds.

I prefer MaxU's solution because of the speed, but with Tarashypka's solution I also learned how to use lambda function with DataFrame.

Thank you very very much to all of you.

Best regards and wishes.